# Can't Make a Bootable USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I'm attempting to make a bootable USB for using 20.04 so my mother in law can use a live version and see if she likes it.  I have been using Rufus and followed the directions listed here:
[Create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

I have not been able to make one yet that works although I have done this in the past without problems.  I have used 3 different branded USB's 2 of which I had older versions on that worked fine in the past.  I have also attempted this on 2 different desktops and a laptop all creating the usb drive which looks fine and error checks fine as well.  The BIOS is set to boot USB first but every computer ignores it like the USB isn't even plugged in.  The USB DOES show in the BIOS but refuses to boot on any computer.

Comment: Did you [verify the ISO download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) before flashing?  Rufus is a great feature-rich tool, but there are a lot of manual and error-prone steps.  If you are having trouble with Rufus, I suggest that you use [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to flash the ISO to your USB.  If you have verified the ISO and you flash with Etcher and you still have problems, consider that you need to troubleshoot the steps with your motherboard BIOS and may need to consult the motherboard documentation for how to boot the USB.

Comment: I did verify the download,  I'll give this etcher a shot and see what happens.  I've never had this occur before, and have been a long time user of Ubuntu.

Comment: What would cause multiple USB sticks to do the same thing between multiple computers?

Comment: Rufus makes either an UEFI only or BIOS only boot able flash drive. Most newer systems are UEFI. If UEFI you want gpt & UEFI, If BIOS you want MBR & CSM (non UEFI). CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. Old systems prior to about 20132 are BIOS only. Other tools generally create a flash drive that boots in UEFI or BIOS mode, but you have to choose from UEFI boot menu, either UEFI:PMAP or PMAP. PMAP may be name or label of your flash drive.

Comment: So my Rufus is only offering BIOS or UEFI no other options?

Comment: Etcher flashed Ubuntu ISOs can be booted in either UEFI or BIOS mode.

Comment: I'll be F'd while I was typing I did it again on one of the same computers, same drive, and it WORKS......

Comment: _"Rufus makes either an UEFI only or BIOS only boot able flash drive."_ That is NOT true for Ubuntu. For Ubuntu, Rufus does create a dual UEFI + BIOS bootable flash drive. Source: I am the developer of Rufus, so I tend to know what limitations apply and I also tend to test these things on a regular basis. Just like Etcher, Rufus flashed Ubuntu ISOs can be booted in either UEFI or BIOS mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)